# Python turtle throws an error on close

Tags: python, tkinter, turtle-graphics

I have this simple program made with Python `2.7.5`. Basically I'm just drawing bunch of random stuff to the screen, but when I close the canvas I get a weird error.

```
import turtle
import random
import time

turtle.hideturtle()

class Mus:

    def __init__(self):
        turtle.setx(random.randint(1,100))
        turtle.sety(random.randint(1,100))
        turtle.circle(random.randint(1,100))

while True:
    Mus()

turtle.exitonclick()
```

When I close the program, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jurehotujec/Desktop/running.py", line 15, in <module>
    Mus()
  File "/Users/jurehotujec/Desktop/running.py", line 12, in __init__
    turtle.circle(random.randint(1,100))
  File "<string>", line 1, in circle
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/turtle.py", line 1908, in circle
    self._rotate(w)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/turtle.py", line 3110, in _rotate
    self._update()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/turtle.py", line 2564, in _update
    self._update_data()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/turtle.py", line 2555, in _update_data
    self._pencolor, self._pensize)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/turtle.py", line 569, in _drawline
    self.cv.coords(lineitem, *cl)
  File "<string>", line 1, in coords
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 2240, in coords
    self.tk.call((self._w, 'coords') + args)))
TclError: invalid command name ".4335016920"
```

What am I doing wrong?
I'm new to python so any help would be appreciated :)

Thanks

Comment: I don't think you should worry about it - ultimately it's going to be from some issue deep inside the standard library around inappropriately flushing events during the exit process. But other than the traceback, it's doing what you want, right?

Comment: yes, but it just look plain ugly :)

Comment: Well, you can `import Tkinter` and then wrap your `Mus()` calls in a try/except block catching `Tkinter.TclError` with `break` in the except body, but it'd be a bad idea, since it would also swallow "real" errors in your application code. But AFAICT there's a legit bug here, so there *should* be a traceback - just not one you should do anything about, the bug isn't related to your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that your loop tries to continue after Tk has destroyed some important objects. You could signal the closing event via a flag:

```
import turtle
import random
import time
import Tkinter as tk



turtle.hideturtle()

closed = False
def on_close():
    global closed
    closed = True
    exit()

# Register hander for close event    
tk._default_root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_close)


class Mus:

    def __init__(self):
        turtle.setx(random.randint(1,100))
        turtle.sety(random.randint(1,100))
        turtle.circle(random.randint(1,100))

# check the flag
while not closed:
    Mus()





turtle.exitonclick()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
from turtle import *

tim = Turtle()

my_screen = Screen()

#my_screen.exitonclick()

tim.forward(100)
my_screen.exitonclick()
```